# I want to use my Minecraft Java Texture Pack on Windows 10, is this possible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I've made my own texture pack/resource pack for Minecraft Java Is it possible to make it work for Minecraft windows 10, if so please help

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your exact question is: Yes, by playing Java Edition on Windows 10 (which I recommend anyway).

But you probably mean "Windows 10 edition" (or MCPE or MCBE or …), in that case, no, that is a completely separate game. There are probably conversion tools online, but they'll never be perfect, because there are some blocks and items that are exclusive to MCPE, just like there are blocks and items that are exclusive to MCJava.